# UnknownFieldException only in spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, xstream

I use XStream to unmarshal Data.xml files.
When I run it with my main() function it works perfectly, but when I try to run it through my boot app, it gives me UnknownFieldException.

> Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$UnknownFieldException: No such field workshop.tokenizer.data.Attributes.attribute
>   ---- Debugging information ----
>   message             : No such field workshop.tokenizer.data.Attributes.attribute
>   field               : attribute
>   class               : workshop.tokenizer.data.Attributes
>   required-type       : workshop.tokenizer.data.Attributes
>   converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
>   class[1]            : workshop.tokenizer.data.DataObj
>   class[2]            : java.util.ArrayList
>   converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter
>   class[3]            : workshop.tokenizer.wrappers.DataObjects
>   version             : 1.4.9

when i'm calling this method, creating Main object fail with this exception, but if I call the same line from "public static void main..." it works perfectly

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/test")
public ResponseEntity<SFRecord> execute(@RequestBody RequestDto json)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, FileNotFoundException {
    Request request = json.convert();
    Main main = new Main();
    RequestObj reqObj = main.execute(request.getSentence());
    ResponseEntity<SFRecord> result = restTemplate.exchange(parserUrl, HttpMethod.POST,
            new HttpEntity<RequestObj>(reqObj), SFRecord.class);
    return result;

}
```

inside Main is use this line to unmarshal Data.xml

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("Files/Data.xml");
    objects = (DataObjects) xstream.fromXML(reader);
```

any ideas why the strange behavior?

Thanks

> Update

I noticed that the XStreamAlias annotations are being ignored, so I added 
xstream.autodetectAnnotations(true);
but now I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: wrappers.DataObjects cannot be cast to wrappers.DataObjects
```

I'm using this line to unmarshal the xml:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("Files/Data.xml");    
DataObjects objects = (DataObjects) xstream.fromXML(reader);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
xstream.setClassLoader(DataObjects.class.getClassLoader());
```

fixed it.